# regex negative lookbehind is doing a normal lookbehind or gives an error

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get regex to capture some data with a negative lookbehind so it won't match if a certain string preceeds it. I know there are two basic formats but neither are working. **I'm doing this in a search app and can't use java to augment so the solution has to be purely with regex**.

This format gives me an error saying "Regular Expression syntax-error: invalid quantifier"

`(?<!Product) Type : (.*?)<`

This format acts a normal lookbehind and captures only when Type is preceded by Product:

`(?!=Product) Type : (.*?)<`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `(?<!` is definitely the right syntax for negative lookbehind in `java.util.regex`, but are you sure that your search app is using `java.util.regex` and not a different regex implementation such as ORO?

Comment: hmmm. I hadn't considered that. I've been using it for awhile now and the app itself is written in java and up until this point has acted accordingly. does ORO not allow negative lookbehinds?

Comment: `(?!=Product)` isn't a lookbehind, it's a negative **lookahead** for the literal string `=Product`.  It can't possibly be working the way you say it is.  You need to read **[this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)**, because you've got some wrong ideas about lookarounds.

Comment: @AlanMoore I have read that site. Its what I used when I started learning regex. What confused me was other sites saying negative lookbehinds exist. I often refer to this [regex cheat-sheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/download/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet-v1/png/) that clearly states that the options for negative lookbehinds are either `?!=` or `?<!` and it also seems that other people are contradicting what you said here. Giving your reputation, I'm taking your comment into consideration, but I got it work with the answer provided below... sooo IDK. Is that cheatsheet incorrect?

Comment: @AlanMoore it is definitely working... so I am thoroughly confused now.

Comment: I don't know of any regex flavor that uses `(?!=` for lookbehinds.  On the other hand, I *do* know that cheat sheet is crap.  It's a self-contradicting melange of features drawn (unattributed) from several different regex flavors.  Notice how it says `<` and `>` have to be escaped if you want to match them literally (untrue), while also saying `\<` and `\>` are word boundaries (not true in Java or any of the other Perl-derived flavors).

Comment: @AlanMoore interesting. Will keep this in mind. I mostly use it as a reference character classes and string replacements anyways.

Comment: @AlanMoore, so I think the confusion might be just the terms used in how you are saying that regex doesn't have negative lookbehinds. Or maybe something regarding @IanRoberts comment about `java.util.regex` having it but most others not. If you understand what I mean, I'd love to know thoughts on the matter.

Comment: I think @Ian's right and your app is using ORO, or maybe [Jakarta Regexp](http://jakarta.apache.org/regexp/), which also doesn't support lookbehinds.  But every flavor I know of that *does* support them uses `(?<=…)` for *positive* lookbehind and `(?<!…)` for *negative* lookbehind.

Comment: @AlanMoore thanks for the input. I think your right with that. I'll ask the developers about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
(?<!Product)[ ]Type[ ]:[ ](.*?)<
```

This should do what you want.  You have to wrap the spaces in  brackets `[]`

It will not match:

`Product Type : xyz<`

but it will match and capture `xyz`:

`Other Type : xyz<`

Comment: but the clarification is always nice!